# Webdriverでの「Timed out waiting for driver server to start」

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

すみません。PHP、slenium、chromedriverを使いスクレイピングをしています。不規則かつ頻繁に「Timed out waiting for driver server to start」のエラーが出るのですが、原因が全くわかりません。どなたか解決策をご存知でしたらお教えください。

また、現時点で関係性は不明ですが、わかっていることとして、スクレイピング中に例外を投げた際、quit()の処理がなされていなかった為、プロセスにchromedriverがかなり溜まってしまっているようです。これは影響を及ぼすのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverのインスタンスがドライバーを起動できなかったというエラーなんです。恐らく、使用されてるバージョンが適切ではないでしょう。

とりあえず、以下の修正方法を試してみてください。

- ChromeDriverを[最新版](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)にする
- ChromeDriverのバージョンによって、Chromeのバージョンを適切のにする（例えば、`ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16`の場合は`Chrome 80`を使用と良い
- Workspace(プロジェクト）をクリーンして、再作成する

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。ChromeDriver、Chromeの共にversionを上げることによる弊害があるのかないのかが気になるところなので、調べてから検討したいと思います。